# Memory error on read_csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, memory

I am facing a dtype Warning in Python when I try to read a csv file. I have check the similar questions, providing values for dtype doesn`t help, it gives the same warning and Memory error. I am working with Fannie Mae performance data set, the columns that are found for mixed type are either empty value or a year in the format mm/yyyy. First I put them str, then object but non of these help. Could it be that the file is so big (443,15MB) and my computer can not process it? I have core 2 duo processor on 2 GHz with 3 Gb RAM memory.

Here is the piece of code that makes the problem

```
data=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(settings.DATA_DIR,f),header=None,names=HEADERS[prefix],sep='|',index_col=False,
                         dtype={"zero_balance_date": str, "last_paid_installment_date": object, "foreclosure_date": object})
```

Here is the warning:

> DtypeWarning: Columns (15,16) have mixed types. Specify dtype option
>   on import or set low_memory=False.

Putting `low_memory=False` also doesn`t do the job.